# Why I cannot remove the cell in my jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

See my method

```
public void removeRow(int[] selectedRow) {
    int len = selectedRow.length;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        data.remove(selectedRow[i]);
    }
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

this is the error callstack

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
        at table.MyTableModel.removeRow(MyTableModel.java:89)
        at table.Tables$2.actionPerformed(Tables.java:61)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)

I am using static ArrayList data as data holder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove a row, your tables indices are adjusted/decremented on each remove resulting in the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You could remove the rows in reverse order to guard against this:

```
for (int i = selectedRow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   data.removeRow(selectedRow[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 Ohh, nice...assuming the `selectedRows` or in ascending order ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as soon as you remove a row, the `selectedRow` indices no longer match the rows in the `data` list

So for example, if I have two rows and I want to remove rows 0 & 1, the moment I remove row 0, row 1 no longer exists (it becomes 0)

What you need to do is create a tempory list that contains the rows you actually want to remove...

```
List<MyRowData> toDelete = new ArrayList<MyRowData>(selectedRow.length);
for(int index : selectedRow) {
    toDelete.add(data.get(index));
}
```

The you should simply be able to use [`List#removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to remove the rows to be delete from the `data` list

```
data.removeAll(toDelete);
```